# How to handle enum values in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a `subscription` table in my database.

I would like to have a `state` column which will have any one of the following values

```
Valid
Invalid
Cancelled
In Trial
Non Renewing
Future
```

Can someone explain how to use these values as enum values in rails 4?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Credit to: https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/

Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database, but can be queried by name. Example:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end

# conversation.update! status: 0
conversation.active!
conversation.active? # => true
conversation.status  # => "active"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.archived!
conversation.archived? # => true
conversation.status    # => "archived"

# conversation.update! status: 1
conversation.status = "archived"

# conversation.update! status: nil
conversation.status = nil
conversation.status.nil? # => true
conversation.status      # => nil
```

Scopes based on the allowed values of the enum field will be provided as well. With the above example, it will create an active and archived scope.

You can set the default value from the database declaration, like:

```
create_table :conversations do |t|
  t.column :status, :integer, default: 0
end
```

Good practice is to let the first declared status be the default.

Finally, it's also possible to explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer with a Hash:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1 }
end
```

Note that when an Array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, :active is mapped to 0 as it's the first element, and :archived is mapped to 1. In general, the i-th element is mapped to i-1 in the database.

Therefore, once a value is added to the enum array, its position in the array must be maintained, and new values should only be added to the end of the array. To remove unused values, the explicit Hash syntax should be used.

In rare circumstances you might need to access the mapping directly. The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name:

```
Conversation.statuses # => { "active" => 0, "archived" => 1 }
```

Use that class method when you need to know the ordinal value of an enum:

```
Conversation.where("status <> ?", Conversation.statuses[:archived])
```

Where conditions on an enum attribute must use the ordinal value of an enum.

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: Unfortunately, This only works in rails4.1. I dont want to upgrade my app to rails 4.1 for now.

Comment: @cevaris I originally copied that answer from rails documentation page. Not from the link you mentioned. I hope rails copied the code from the source you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

You can use gem called [Workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow). It enables you to use custom statuses and gracefully handle transitions between states. I've used it on many Rails3 and Rails 4 apps.

Example from the documentation.

```
class Article
  include Workflow
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end
end
```

And later:

```
article = Article.new
article.accepted? # => false
article.new? # => true
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** *My answer here does not use [ActiveRecord magic enums](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). What I suggest below works for any DB library (like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/)), and I happen to think it slightly more robust. For example, it does not rely on automatic ordering of values, and it uses foreign key constraints in the RDBMS to ensure that your value is valid (unlike the ActiveRecord solution). However, it is not the Rails idiomatic methodology. See Giri's answer (a copy/paste of the documentation page) for the idiomatic answer.*

---

1. Create a `states` table in your database with these string values populated along with a unique ID, e.g.

   ```
   states
   id | name 
   ---+--------------
    1 | Valid
    2 | Invalid
    3 | Cancelled
    4 | In Trial
    5 | Non Renewing
    6 | Future
   ```
2. Use a standard foreign-key association in your `subscription` table referencing an entry from `states`.
3. In your models, create a `State` class with constants matching the IDs, e.g.:

   ```ruby
   class State < ActiveRecord::Base
     VALID   = 1
     INVALID = 2
     # etc.
   end
   ```

Now you are a) guaranteed that your table data is valid, and b) you can use convenient references such as asking for `subscriptions`

```ruby
Subscription.where( state_id: State::VALID )
```

Comment: That's not the way Rails 4 handles enum. Your answer is not wrong, but it not the Rails 4 way that op question needs... Take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: @rizidoro Thank you for the information. I personally think the Rails way is less ideal, since it relies on enforcing referential integrity in Ruby instead of the database. Giri: please switch the accepted answer to your copy/paste of the Rails documentation.

Comment: I don't like the idea of hardcoding IDs as constants. It couples your code with data in the database. I've done that in the past and I hated it so much when I have to deploy the app to multiple environments (separate db), or to write automated tests...Also I'd avoid using integers as states, you will find it very counter intuitive when you have to write custom queries or extensions and you can't recall which number means which without having to look at the code.